# Dynamic meta tags using access database

Tags: asp.net, ms-access

I am trying to generate dynamic meta tags from access database based on this [post](http://forums.asp.net/t/1411954.aspx/1).

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    OleDbParameter spar = new OleDbParameter("@Title", Request["Title"]);
    string query = "SELECT * FROM storedata WHERE Title = @Title";
    OleDbConnection myconnection = new OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["accessConnectionString5"].ConnectionString);
    OleDbCommand SqlCmd = null;
    SqlCmd = new OleDbCommand(query, myconnection);

    SqlCmd.Parameters.Add(spar);

    SqlCmd.Connection.Open();
    SqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


    OleDbDataAdapter ad = new OleDbDataAdapter(SqlCmd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    ad.Fill(dt);


    title.InnerHtml = dt.Rows[0]["Title"].ToString();
    keywords.Attributes.Add("content", dt.Rows[0]["Title"].ToString());


   // Closing the SQL connection
      SqlCmd.Connection.Close();

}
```

But I am getting error '**System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Parameter @Title has no default value**'.

Answer (score 0):

You say `WHERE Title = @Title` but I cannot see where you have assigned a value to this parameter.

```
SqlCmd = new OleDbCommand(query, myconnection); 
SqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Title","a title");
```